# How to mark cloned form from inline as deleted so Django knows what to save and what not to save

Tags: html, jquery, django, django-forms

views.py:

```
def device_add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        device_frm = DeviceForm(request.POST) 
        dd_form = DeviceDetailForm(request.POST)
        
        di_formset = inlineformset_factory(Device, DeviceInterface, fields=('moduletype', 'firstportid', 'lastportid'),widgets={  'firstportid':TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'e.g. TenGigabitEthernet1/0/1'}), 'lastportid':TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'eg. TenGigabitEthernet1/0/48'})},extra=1,max_num=3, can_delete=False)
        di_form=di_formset(request.POST)
        if device_frm.is_valid():
        # Create and save the device
        # new_device here is the newly created Device object
            new_device = device_frm.save()
            if dd_form.is_valid():
                # Create an unsaved instance of device detail
                deviceD = dd_form.save(commit=False)
                # Set the device we just created above as this device detail's device
                deviceD.DD2DKEY = new_device              
                deviceD.save()
                if di_form.is_valid():
                    deviceI=di_form.save(commit=False) 
                    print(deviceI)
                    for instances in deviceI:          
                        instances.I2DKEY=new_device
                        instances.save()
                    return render(request, 'interface/device_added.html',{'devices':Device.objects.all()})
                return render(request,'interface/device_add.html',{'form':device_frm, 'dd_form': dd_form, 'di_form':di_form})
            return render(request,'interface/device_add.html',{'form':device_frm, 'dd_form': dd_form, 'di_form':di_form})
        return render(request,'interface/device_add.html',{'form':device_frm, 'dd_form': dd_form, 'di_form':di_form})
    else:
        device_frm = DeviceForm()
        dd_form = DeviceDetailForm()
        di_formset = inlineformset_factory(Device, DeviceInterface, fields=('moduletype', 'firstportid', 'lastportid'), widgets={  'firstportid':TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'e.g. TenGigabitEthernet1/0/1'}), 'lastportid':TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'eg. TenGigabitEthernet1/0/48'})},extra=1, max_num=3, can_delete=False)
        di_form=di_formset(queryset = DeviceInterface.objects.none())
        return render(request,'interface/device_add.html',{'form':device_frm, 'dd_form': dd_form, 'di_form':di_form})
```

HTML:

```
       {{di_form.management_form}}
       <div id = "rowAddition">
       {% for form in di_form %}
       <div>
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
           <label for="{{di_form.moduletype.id_for_label}}">Module Type<span
                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            {{form.moduletype}}               
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
           <label for="{{di_form.firstportid.id_for_label}}">First Port ID<span
                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            {{form.firstportid}}
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
           <label for="{{di_form.lastportid.id_for_label}}">Last Port ID <span
                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            {{form.lastportid}}
          </div>
         </div>  
        </div>
       </div>
       {%endfor%}

       <div id="empty-form" style="display: none;">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
           <label for="{{dd_form.moduletype.id_for_label}}">Module Type<span
                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            {{di_form.empty_form.moduletype}}               
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
           <label for="{{di_form.firstportid.id_for_label}}">First Port ID<span
                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            {{di_form.empty_form.firstportid}}
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
           <label for="{{di_form.lastportid.id_for_label}}">Last Port ID <span
                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            {{di_form.empty_form.lastportid}}
          </div>
         </div>                                
         <div class="col-md-1">
          <div class="form-group">
           <div class="text-sm-center">
            <br />
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-rounded"
              id="removerow" style="display: none;" data-toggle="modal"><i class="dripicons- 
              minus" ></i></button>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <!--more rows-->
         <div id='morerows'></div>
```

Script:

```
let changeFlag=0;
let maxrow = $('#id_deviceinterface_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS').attr('value');
let totalForms = $('#id_deviceinterface_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
console.log(maxrow)
console.log(totalForms)
$('#deleteConfirmation').modal('hide');
function portidChange(val) {
    changeFlag = 1;
    if (val =="")
    changeFlag = 0;
    
}
$('#addrow').click(function () {      
    let totalForms = $('#id_deviceinterface_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    console.log(totalForms)        
    $('#empty-form #removerow').css('display','block');       
    let wholerowclone = $('#empty-form').clone();        
    $('#morerows').append(wholerowclone.html().replace(/__prefix__/g, totalForms));
    $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').attr('value', (parseInt (totalForms))+1);  
    changeFlag=0;    
    if(totalForms==maxrow) {            
        $('#addrow').attr("disabled", true);
        $('#addrow').attr("class","btn btn-rounded btn-danger");
        $('#addrow i').attr("class","");
        $('#addrow').html("Reached max limit");
    }      
})
$(document).on('click', '#removerow', function () {
    let totalForms = $('#id_deviceinterface_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    console.log(totalForms + " total forms");
    let actualformcount = totalForms-1;        
    if(changeFlag==1) {
        console.log("changeFlag=1");
        $('#removerow').attr('data-target', '#deleteConfirmation')           
        $('#deleteConfirmation').modal('show');
        $('#removerowConfirmed').click(function () {
            console.log("clicked")
            $('#removerow').closest('#morerows.row').remove();
            $('#deleteConfirmation').modal('hide');
            if(actualformcount < maxrow) {
                $('#addrow').attr("disabled", false)
                $('#addrow').attr("class","btn btn-outline-success btn-rounded")
                $('#addrow i').attr("class","dripicons-plus")
                $('#addrow').html("+") 
            }  
        })
    }
    else {
        console.log("ChangeFlag 0");
        $('#id_deviceinterface_set-TOTAL_FORMS').attr('value', (parseInt (totalForms))-1);
        $(this).closest('#morerows .row').remove();
        if(actualformcount < maxrow){
            $('#addrow').attr("disabled", false)
            $('#addrow').attr("class","btn btn-outline-success btn-rounded")
            $('#addrow i').attr("class","dripicons-plus")
            $('#addrow').html("+")
        } 
    }         
});
```

I have this set of codes that is intended to control the number of form created from inline using a button. This is working out perfectly well. But when it comes to saving, if i were to delete something. I can only delete the last cloned row and all the rest of the data which is not deleted are saved. But if i delete a cloned row that is in the middle, the data saved goes haywire. For example my code allow cloning of 3 times. So with clone + original = 4. If i were to delete a row in the middle. Lets say row 1(1st clone). It saves the original(correct), never save the 1st clone (correct), saves the 3rd row (correct) and somehow last row data is lost. Can anyone advise me what to do? I have been stuck here for 3 days already.

One more problem: Notice this a few days ago. Because i set the view to refresh the page with the details if any field is key in wrongly, any cloned rows with the **-** button disappears. Can anyone explain to me why is this happening?